# Are threads intended for parallel IO rather than CPU?

Tags: multithreading, io, parallel-processing, cpu, process

In Guido Van Rossum's 2012 Pycon talk, he says the following about threads:

> If you use threads for what they were originally meant for, OS-level threads are meant for doing parallel IO, not for doing parallel computation. [[source]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBRMq2Ioxsc#t=34m0s)

Traditionally, discussions about processes-vs-threads revolve around differences between scheduling, cost of context switches, or cost of sharing resources.

However, I have never learned about, or heard of, a notion that one is necessarily better than another for CPU-intensive tasks versus IO. If there is essentially a 1-1 relationship between a process and a thread (not always something you can assume), does it even matter, from a CPU-vs-IO perspective, which one to use?

The standard pthread documentation does not shed light on this particular claim; does someone know a better source?

Are there common cases where it is better to use one versus another when architecting software which is known to have bottlenecks in one of these areas?

Comment: I think he's talking about threads in Python, not threads in general.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. It asks for discussion, which is a poor fit for the format here (and is actually against the guidelines). It's multiple questions in a single post, which is also against the guidelines here. Finally, SO isn't [a link farm or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549) or a [personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553). Questions asking to point you to links about something are also inappropriate here.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I was thinking this too; but he does specifically say "OS-level" threads, which to me implied something stronger than something Python-specific.

Comment: That is just to provide a contrast between OS-level and lightweight Python threads.  Lightweight python threads can only interleave operations, they can't perform IO and computations simultaneously.

Comment: Guido's statement is valid on single core CPUs only. Even given the lightweight context switch between the threads of a single process on Linux x86, it is still more heavy-weight then user-level threading. And since you are only running on a single core any additional overhead leads to performance degradation. This is not true on multicore chips where each thread can be scheduled on different core and cache sharing between threads can lead to better performance than running separate processes that communicate with message passing.

Comment: Ok, now after I've dived enough into the subject I realise that Guido was talking about threading in Python and the dreaded Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) that makes Python threads really usable for asynchronous I/O only. For parallel computing on the same node one should use the `multiprocessing` module and not the threading one.

Comment: @HristoIliev: No, threads are invented and designed for *concurrency*, not parallellism. To let a program continue to do computation while waiting for IO. That's the intention of threads. Some language implementation and virtual machines, like JVM, has better support for parallelism with threads than others. CPython does not have good support for it. But he isn't talking about Python threads, he is talking about threads in general.

Answer (score 0):

Most OSes offer multiple threads per process.

These threads can be used for plain computation without any interaction, for computation with occasional interaction with other threads (typically from the same process), or for short bursts of computation interacting with I/O.

The OS design generally doesn't care what you do with a thread; the designers are expecting all three and provide efficient mechanisms to priortize, schedule execution, and enable reliable thread interactions with other threads.

I can believe that Guido was talking about threads built into Python.   What those threads do are what the designer says they do.  If he used them on only for I/O, then they are only intended for I/O.

Given that Python is an interpreter, offering computational threads would be possible but strange; since interpreters tend to be 10x as slow as compiled code, all you'd have was a parallel program that ran 10x slower than it could.  People that want parallel computation want answers fast, and tend not to use interpreters for this reason.

Comment: Your last statement is not always true. It is sometimes faster to quickly prototype the model in Python with NumPy and that might run nearly as fast as compiled code. Then you will actually get the answer faster measured from the moment you start to implement the model because you will save on development and debugging time.

Comment: @HristoIliev: yes, Python might give your *first* answer faster.  And for interactive and modest-CPU bound answers (covering lots of applications), Python gives answers fast enough, which is why people like it.    But if you task is seriously CPU bound, Python is probably not the way to get it (threaded or not), especially if you are going to run the application more than once.

Comment: No, threads are invented and designed for concurrency, not parallellism. To let a program continue to do computation while waiting for IO. That's the intention of threads. Some language implementation and virtual machines, like JVM, has better support for parallelism with threads than others. CPython does not have good support for it. But he isn't talking about Python threads, he is talking about threads in general.

Comment: Threads are an abstraction of parallelism; they may be backed up real processors, or they may be simulated by mulitiplexing one or more CPUs.   In this sense, they represent parallelism.  They can be used for concurrency, but it is very practical to think of threads as potential parallel tasks and allow the OS/runtime system determine what really happens.  I and many other have built real systems that provide this perspective and it works just fine, thank you.